# Capitalize each word in R separated by ;

Tags: r

This data I have and I want to capitalize each word.

```
Cycling Refrigerated Thermal mass Dryer; No-loss Condensate Drain; storage tanks for load/no load screw compressors <50 HP
```

I want this result.

```
Cycling Refrigerated Thermal Mass Dryer; No-loss Condensate Drain; Storage Tanks for Load/No Load Screw Compressors <50 HP;
```

Comment: This is called "title case". If your text is called `text` then `stringr::str_to_title(text)` will get what you are looking for.

Comment: easiest solution would be `stringr::str_to_title()`, but then "for" would also be capitalised. Should "for" also be capitalised? Also, it is not clear what is the issue with ";", as it does not seem to change much if you are expecting a single character vector of length one.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out!

```
library(stringr)

str <- "Cycling Refrigerated Thermal mass Dryer; No-loss Condensate Drain; storage tanks for load/no load screw compressors <50 HP"

str_to_title(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tools::toTitleCase(string)

[1] "Cycling Refrigerated Thermal Mass Dryer; No-Loss Condensate Drain; Storage Tanks for Load/No Load Screw Compressors <50 HP"
```

Note that the word `for` has not been capitalized. This replicates exactly what you want